# Create new static address dynamically in Java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

When developing a Web Application in Java, launching in Tomcat, I need to be able to create (dynamically) a new static address (link,URL) in the server that will be used to view the information of a new item, let's call it `new_item_001`, which have been just created by one user.

Say I want to create a new address

```
www.domain.com/webapp/items/new_item_001
```

which can be used to render a view of the contents of `new_item_001`.

Which is the best approach to do this?

- Should I dynamically create a new servlet class for this view?
- Should I dynamically create the folder `items` and one html file `new_item_001` for this item inside of it?
- Should I edit the server address mapping rules to create this static address and map it to a central servlet which somehow knows which item to display?

I understand the question is ill posed, and that I am far from even understanding the issue, so I would like some guidelines on what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above.

You should simply have a servlet mapped to `/items/*`. When a request come to this servlet, analyze the actual path of the request, extract the part after `/items/` to know the actual value (`new_item_001`) in your example, get the data corresponding to this item from the database, and send it to the browser.

Using a true MVC framework like Spring MVC would make that much easier. You could simply map a method of a controller using

```
@RequestMapping("/items/{itemId}")
public Item getItem(@PathVariable("itemId") String itemId) {
    ...
}
```

and let the framework do all the URL parsing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tackle this in a simple way. Creating a servlet for each created item would be overkill and become quite cumbersome to manage after a successful run of the application for some time.

Changing/editing server mapping URL looks very naive approach and is not scaling too. Let configuration be there and change them only when you actually need to change them.

My suggestion is to create one servlet that handles all these requests. For example, you may save item information on a datastore or on file system(i.e images uploaded by user etc..). Next time a GET request is received by the application to fetch saved information of an item, servlet should be able to reference the item on database associated with the item id on the URL. If you don't wish to expose item id/surrogate key in the database, you can also have a simple mapping between them by implementing your own logic. Frameworks like Spring MVC do a good job in mapping URLs to resources like this should you wish to use a framework.

Additionally to minimize the number of requests to the same item, you can also implement an HTTP caching strategy(i.e. ETAG, If-Modified-Since) by instructing your web server at the time of first GET request from a user.